# Navigation bar is not visible in my app Android (Eclipse)

Tags: android, eclipse, navigationbar

When I create an Android app in Eclipse, navigation bar is not displayed in `activity_main`:

[image]

Does anyone know how to fix?

Comment: What's the app theme in manifest file?

Comment: android:theme="@style/AppTheme"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to be sure that your android:theme in the Android manifest is like this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
</style>
```

And since Android 5 actionBar is not used, is recommended to use Toolbar. Your Activity has to extend AppCompatActivity

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
//...

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    //...
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.appbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }
}
```

You can custom the toolbar:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" >

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer.
I'am a beginner in android developpement so it is my first app using navigation drawer , i followed every step in a tutorial so i reconizet that in the tuto app i can see a navigation bar but i don't know why mine is not.

Comment: i added the code you gave to me but it shows an error while starting the app that said "unfortunatly app_name has stopped" !

Comment: What is the exception that is through in your console?? You have included the support library in your gradle:
dependencies {
    //...
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
}

Comment: the exception is : java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: If you can paste the whole exception we can help you.

Comment: i have a question, please !
Where i have to put the code you gave to me because i have the activity_main, a drawer_list_item and fragment_layout !?

Comment: I dont know how is your main_activity.xml but if you want to include an ActionBar(toolbar) you have to include this: android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar in your layout. And after that, in your activity: Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.appbar); setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

Comment: Ok ! there is the link of the tutorial if you want to know the whole code i create
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WTRNI_r7ccI